# Initializing a QApplication fails in release mode of MSVC

Tags: c++, qt, release

I am creating a Qt application in MSVC.

On my `main` method, I create a QApplication with `QApplication app(argc, argv);`

When I build the program in `DEBUG mode` the program works fine. However, when I build the program in `RELEASE mode`, the program closes on the `QApplication app(argc, argv);` line.

I get no error message when the program closes, so I believe that it is no crash, but some built in QApplicaiton response to an error.

Any suggestions on why this might be happening?

Comment: How exactly does it crash (maybe there are some error messages)?

Comment: Since it is release mode, no errors appear. The programs simply closes...

Comment: Are you linking to the correct debug/release flavour of Qt libraries?

Comment: How are your QT libraries built? Maybe you only have debug versions of them, but not the release versions?

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I link it to the release versions of the qt dll's. Not the ...d.dll's.

Comment: And you are absolutely certain it crashes on the `QApplication app(argc, argv);` line?

Comment: @thuga Yes I am, because I incerted `getch();` every where in the code, to wait for user input. And it is at the `QApplication app(argc, argv);` line that it closes the program.

Comment: is it possible that you are using MSVC version of QT libs? I think mingw and MSVC use different C++ **ABI**.

Comment: @ibre5041 thanks for the response, but I am using the msvc2013 versions since I am MSVC Express 2013...

Comment: and is it possible that you also loaded some other libs - compiled by some other compiler? This really looks like some library ABI problem. QApplication should not crash easily.

Comment: You were right, some dlls from Qt were missing. It was difficult to figure out which, because they showed no warnings. The way I found out was using DependancyWalker and checking not only first layer dependencies, but also deeper layers from the Qt dlls.

Comment: @BrunoLubascher If that solved your problem, you might consider self-answering your question. That way, the solution is available for anyone who finds your question by searching for a similar issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that Qt needed some dll's that were missing in my programs executable directory.

Because it was release mode, no errors were popping up, so the program simply closed.

To solve it, I had to use [DependencyWalker](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) to figure out which dll's that were used by my program. After finding out which dll's were needed, I placed them on my executable's directory. Everything worked as expected then.